# Mongodb Aggregation: Testing if a field is numeric or alphanumeric and splitting it if it alphanumeric

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I would like to test in Mongodb aggregation (condition) if a particular field is numeric (1, 2, 3) or alphanumeric (3a or 12b or 111a etc). if it numeric just return the value but if it alphanumeric split the string between numbers and letters (or characters). For example:  alphanumeric 12b will be split like so 12 and b.  Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to get the parts you want. Then to overwrite the ageandnum with an array or number you can compare the `number` field.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/19u42WJ6WoQ

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { // Use regex to create a num and string field
    "$addFields": {
      num: {$regexFind: {
        input: '$ageandnum',
        regex: '[0-9]+'
      }},
      string: {$regexFind: {
        input: '$ageandnum',
        regex: '[a-z]+'
      }},
    }
  },

  {
    $addFields: {
      num: "$num.match",
      string: "$string.match",
      
      // Conditionally overwrite ageandnum with an array
      ageandnum: {$cond: [
        {$eq: ["$ageandnum", "$num.match"]},
        "$num.match",
        ["$num.match", "$string.match"]
      ]}
    }
  }

])
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?